# Ruby: How to determine how many variables are being assigned by method caller

Tags: ruby

I would like to have my method change what it returns depending on how many variables are being assigned by the caller. Is there a way to query this in the method? Or is there a way to encode a 2-value return so that the second value will be ignored if an assignment destination is not supplied? Thanks! --Myles

```
def foo
  if <two-vars-being-assigned>
    return [:bar, :baz] 
  else
    return :bar
  end
end

x, y = foo

# I want x to get :bar, not [:bar, :baz]
x = foo
```

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `if local_variables.size == 2 ...`. See [Kernel#local_variables](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Kernel.html#method-i-local_variables). This seems like an odd bit of code.

Comment: The context is that this is a small piece of utility code I use across multiple scripts. I want the return to be different for the different contexts w/o adding the small bit of complexity of adding an input parameter to control the output. The question was really more about trying to learn more about arcane Ruby details than trying to solve the problem at hand (which has many simpler, more obvious solutions). And thanks to all of these answers, I did learn more!

Comment: A little more context is that I had already used this piece of utility code in many places and I wanted to add the 2cd return value w/o affecting the functionality of all the places I had already used it.

Answer (score 5):

If you *really* wanted to, you could return an object which responds to `to_ary`. You could even monkey patch `Symbol` in your example with a `to_ary` method.

But … NO. Just NO.

```
class Symbol
  def to_ary
    [:bar, :baz]
  end
end

def foo
  :bar
end

a = foo
a #=> :bar

b, c = foo
b #=> :bar
c #=> :baz
```

Whatever kind of object you return, it will violate the *Single Responsibility Principle*, since it acts *both* as whatever the return value is supposed to act as *and* as a proxy for splitting itself into two return values.

Just … NO. Seriously. NO.

Comment: o m g ... this makes my day :-)

Answer (score 4):

I would agrue that this is not possible. When you call `x, y = foo` then `foo` gets evaluated first and therefore runs and returns before the assignment is done. Furthermore, I see no easy and reasonable way to make a method aware of the code structure at the place from which it was called.

Why don't you just handle this at the place in which you call that method:

```
def foo
  [:bar, :baz] 
end

x, y = foo
x = foo.first
```

Answer (score 2):

What happens to the return-value is clearly outside the method's scope. You shouldn't attempt to detect what's going on there.

The obvious solution is to solve it on caller's side, e.g. via:

```
def foo
  [:bar, :baz]
end

x, = foo

# or more specific

x, _ = foo
```

You could also yield the values to a block and just define the block arguments you're interested in:

```
def foo
  yield :bar, :baz
end

foo do |x|
  p x: x
  # prints {:x=>:bar}
end

foo do |x, y|
  p x: x, y: y
  # prints {:x=>:bar, :y=>:baz}
end
```

If the conditional is important, you could check the block's [`arity`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Proc.html#method-i-arity):

```
def foo(&block)
  if block.arity == 2
    yield :bar, :baz
  else
    yield :bar
  end
end
```